# How to handle resource not found with AngularJS routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a traditional data driven web application we often attempt to load a resource based on an ID passed in the URL. If the resource does not exist we return a 404 page.

How should we achieve the same thing in AngularJS? I've followed the AngularJS phone catalog tutorial and am currently doing the following should the resource not exist (note this uses the Angular `$resource` service):

```
controllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Phone',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $location, Phone) {

    $scope.phone = Phone.get({ phoneId: $routeParams.phoneId }, 
      function(phone) {
        $scope.mainImageUrl = phone.images[0];
      },
      function(response) {
        if (response.status === 404) {
          $location.path('/404'); // show phone not found page
        }
      });
}]);
```

Is this the recommended approach? Considering I will need to do this on virtually every resource I wondered whether it would be better handled within the `$routeProvider`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually use `ngRoute` and provide resources through resovle:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/phone/:phoneId', {
         templateUrl: 'views/phone.html',
         controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl',
         resolve: {
             phone: ['$route', 'Phone', function($route, Phone) {
                 return Phone.get({ phoneId: $route.current.params.phoneId }).$promise
             }]
         }
    });
}]);
```

Now phone declared as dependency of this route and route won't be changed when response return an error. Then if you want to show error page you need listen to `$routeChangeError` event

```
angular.module('myApp').run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
   $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, current, previous, error) {
       if(error.status === 404) {
          $location.path('/404');
       }
   });
}]);
```

If you have multiple resources this approach allow you keep error handling code in one place and clear controllers from this logic that is very convenient

Comment: This works great, thanks. Only problem I spotted is that it should be `if(error.status === 404)` not `if(error.status === '404')`.

Comment: @BenFoster sorry, it was a typo

Comment: Could you explain what Phone is in this example?

Comment: @DanielLarsson Phone is a user defined angular service. I think the code snippet is similar to official angular tutorial. See [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/app/js/services.js)

Answer (score 4):

Internally ngResource uses $http so to handle this kind of situations you could use [http interceptors](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)